# How to get Activity's transition?

Tags: android

I can set transition to an activity use `overridePendingTransition`.
But I can't find method to get these transition.Which API should I use?

for example, some code has used `overridePendingTransition` to set transition for Activity **A**.

Now I have Activity **B**, it need same transition of **B**. But the `overridePendingTransition` operation to **A** is invisible to me .

So I need API to get A's transition. I can't find it after searching the API document.

Comment: Which method you didn't find??

Comment: @PG_Android The animation id I set for an activity by `overridePendingTransition`

Comment: Have you created anim folder in res folder??

Comment: @PG_Android Having edited my quesiton